# Finding a size of maximum subset of graph in which each vertex a degree atleast p

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a undirected graph. How to find the size of maximum subset of vertices of the graph in which each vertex has at degree atleast p, where the degree in subset is find among the vertices in subset only.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a nice problem (with an easy solution once you look at it the right way), but I'm struggling to find a hint for you that wouldn't immediately give it away :)

Comment: It seems to be some sort of clique type graph problem which is NP-Hard but may be due to query of size only, there is some way to solve it. Maximizing the size gives me some hint of using maximum matching algorithm but after spending time modelling it in matching, no success is still there.

Comment: How about this: Look at your original graph. Which vertices can never be part of the subset you are looking for?

Comment: Straight away, we can remove vertices which have degree less than p.

Comment: Exactly. Don't forget to remove the edges that belonged to those vertices as well. Then look at the graph you have now: Which of its vertices cannot be part of your subset? (Not an actual question ;-) )

Comment: Okay now it seems to be like we will keep removing vertices unless we reach condition when no vertex has degree less than p.

Comment: Yes! You basically have the solution now :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Liked your way...

Answer (score 1):

Vertices of degree less than p can never be part of the solution. Remove them entirely, including their edges. Look at the new graph and repeat, etc.

When this process stops, all vertices have degree at least p.

Then, look at the connected components of that graph and pick the largest one! (As Evgeny Kluev correctly points out, this is unnecessary of course. In my head, the remaining subgraph should have been connected, but of course the original problem makes no such demands.)

Comment: Nice solution. Only the last part (with the connected components) is not needed.